# Accessing $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) in Magento

Tags: magento, cart, php

I have troubles using the following functions in Magento:

```
<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

I am using them in a custom phtml file called from a cms page with the code :

```
<?php print $this->getLayout()
                 ->createBlock("core/template")
                 ->setTemplate("page/cms/aide/affichage-demo.phtml")
                 ->toHtml(); ?>
```

The `$this->getAddToCartUrl($_product)` or `$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)` are just not returning nothing.
The `$_product` is not the issue as other functions are returning other attributes well.

the following is working well

```
<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>
```

But this is not :

```
<?php echo $_product->getAddToCartUrl() ?>
```

Any idea of how to get `getAddToCartUrl` and `getPriceHtml` working?

Answer (score 4):

Cart url is

```
 Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);
```

Comment: being a newbie in php, can you help me get the entire syntax right? the following is not working: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You must change the product object variable name to $_product in here:

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible you can create a different block:

```
<?php print $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock("catalog/product_list")
    ->setTemplate("page/cms/aide/affichage-demo.phtml")
    ->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

This code can be accessed from  `url`

```
C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View.php
.it returns  $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
```

`getAddUrl($product, $additional)` can be accessed from `url`

```
C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Helper\Cart.php
```